# Is this an LL(1) grammar? How to solve First - Follow conflict?

Tags: formal-grammars, compilers, parsers

im trying to check if this grammar is LL(1).

S -> L = R 
L -> * L | id 
R -> L | R + R | num

As you can see there is a Left recursion on R production. So i remove that and what i get is:

S -> L = R 
L -> * L | id 
R -> L R' | num R'
R' -> + R R' | ε

Now the problem that i have is that First and Follow set of R' rule have a common non-terminal ("+") and also FIRST(R) and FOLLOW(R') has a common non-terminal. 
So i wonder how to create the parsing table if there's this conflict. My question is: is there a way to solve this problem or simply this isn't an LL(1) grammar?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your original grammar is not only left-recursive, it is also ambiguous. Left-recursion only matters to certain parsing techniques, but ambiguous grammars are, by definition, impossible to parse with a deterministic parser. And removing left-recursion does not in general fix ambiguity.

The ambiguity is in the production

```
R → R + R
```

which allows `1 + 2 + 3` to be parsed in two different ways: as the result of adding `3` to `1 + 2` or as the result of adding `2 + 3` to `1`. (These have the same value, but if the operator had been `-` instead of `+`, the ambiguity would allow two different evaluations.)

The correct way to write this grammar unambiguously is

```
 S → L = R
 L → *L | id
 R → F | R + F
 F → L | num
```

With that grammar, `1 + 2 + 3` can only be parsed as the sum of `1 + 2` and `3`, because `2 + 3` is not an `F`. That makes `+` a left-associative operator, which is the normal usage. (Again, this is clearer if you consider the operator `-`: `1 - 2 - 3` is `-4`, not `0`.)

You can then, if you want to, apply the left-recursion elimination algorithm, to yield:

```
 S → L = R
 L → *L | id
 R → F R'
 R'→ + F R' | ε
 F → L | num
```

Note, however, that after left-recursion elimination, the associativity of `+` is not so clear. With a simple operator grammar like this, left-recursion elimination is essentially the same as the two steps:

1. Change left-associative operators (left-recursive productions) to being right-associative.
2. Left-factor the productions.

Thus, after left-recursion elimination, a left-associative grammar and a right-associative grammar are the same.

Comment: Thank you so much, you helped me a lot! All clear now. I wasn't even thinking about ambiguity of the grammar. Thank you again. @rici

Answer (score 0):

Your factoring is wrong. It should be (written as regular espressions):

$\begin{align*}
  R
    &\to (L \mid \operatorname{num}) (+ R)^*
\end{align*}$

Thus the grammar with left recursion fixed is:

$\begin{align*}
   S  &\to L = R \\
   L  &\to * L \mid \operatorname{id} \\
   R  &\to L R' \mid \operatorname{num} R' \\
   R' &\to + R R' \mid \varepsilon
\end{align*}$

You can check that this doesn't have conflicts.

Comment: Sry isn't this the same as i wrote? I mean the fixed left- recursion @vonbrand